# Simple web dev in python

Tags: python

I used to think Django got everything out of the way and let you quickly mount servers, writing clean code with little to no hassle.

After doing some tinkering and small projects in node.js and the OPA language, I'm no longer convinced. Django feels like a Java stack in comparison. I am, however, still in love with python-the-language, and would like to use it more.

Are there any web frameworks as simple as node.js or OPA, for python?

Comment: node.js changed my perspective on "web frameworks" too.  I'm now working on an async http server with a very similar (event driven) interface, except perl based instead of js; it might be out later this year.  Maybe someone should get it together and do the same thing for python...

Comment: Have a look at http://wiki.python.org/moin/WebFrameworks

Comment: The biggest problem with OPA is that its license requires you to publish your server code..

Comment: Really? Question closed? What part of "is there a web framework similar to node.js but for python" is not a good question?

Answer (score 3):

Something like [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) might be up your street.

Comment: Will take a look and get back to you. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe take a look at [Bottle](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/) or [Werkzeug](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/)

Comment: Will take a look and get back to you. Thanks!